# How to annotate my classes correctly

Tags: java, android, xml, spring

I'm trying annotate my classes correctly so I can use SimpleXML with the android spring framework. My problem is, I'm always getting:

```
E/something(25192): Could not read [class at.something.scanner.Issues]; nested exception is org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=true, name=issues, required=true, type=void) on field 'issues' private java.util.List at.something.scanner.Issues.issues for class at.something.scanner.Issues at line 1
```

and

```
E/something(25192): Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=true, name=issues, required=true, type=void) on field 'issues' private java.util.List at.something.scanner.Issues.issues for class at.something.scanner.Issues at line 1
```

I know I can get rid of the ValueRequiredException by using @ElementList(required=false), but it doesn't solve my problem, because I end up with an empty list.

Request using spring:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());              
Serializer serializer = new Persister(new Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>"));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter(serializer));
ResponseEntity<Issues> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), Issues.class);
Issues tickets = response.getBody();
```

Issues.java:

```
@Root
public class Issues{

@ElementList(name="issues", inline=true)
    private List<Issue> issues;

    public void setIssues(List<Issue> results) {
        this.issues = results;
    }

    public List<Issue> getIssues() {
        return issues;
    }
}
```

Issue.java

```
@Root(name="issue")
public class Issue{

    @Attribute(name="id")
    private String id;
}
```

Sample XML response from server:

```
<issues>
    <issue id="ABC-10">
       <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SingleField" name="Assignee">
          <value>someone</value>
       </field>
    </issue>
    <issue id="ABC-11">
       <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SingleField" name="reporterName">
          <value>someone</value>
       </field>
    </issue>
</issues>
```

I hope someone can give me a hint on how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@ElementList(name="issues", inline=true, entry="Issue")
```

I had the same problem and this did the trick for me. Found this answer here on Stackoverflow.

**EDIT:**

I have tried your example with Simple XML and for class Issue
you have

```
@Element(name="field")
private Field field;
```

missing.

```
public class Field {

     @Element(name = "value", required = true)
     private String value;

     @Attribute(name = "name", required = false)
     private String name;

}
```

Also I used

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Serializer serializer = new Persister(new Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>"));
    File source = new File("sample.xml");
    Issues i = serializer.read(Issues.class, source);

}
```

And I have no error. The object i is loaded correctly with the data from the xml.

Comment: Didn't do the trick for me :( I'm still having the same problem